# Create function in php to generate some html content is good idea?

Tags: php, html, function

For example I have this php function:

```
function generateContent($param1) {
 return '<div class="class" id="'.$param1.'">content...</div>';
}
```

Its something very simple and nothing special, but happens with a lot of small contents that repeat a lot.

I would like to know if is it a good idea in terms of page speed optimization?

I mean running a php function a lot of times to create this content.

Comment: I suggest having a look at templating tools like [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/), [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), [Latte](https://latte.nette.org/en/), etc. Helps you separate logic from your views

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely a bad idea, in my old projects I made things like this as well. Later I discovered that component way of making html content is much more effective.
Today I would rather use templating system with blocks (components) support, so you can easily pass variables to the components and draw them in template with ease. Plus keeping components in their own files makes whole project more sustainable.

If you used for example Latte templating system in php, it would look like this:

Defining template (this would be for example Card.latte)

```
{define card, $name, $collapsed}
<h3>{$name}</h3>
...
{/define}
```

Using it (ex.: ProductDetail.latte):

```
{include card, 'John Doe', true}
```